# How should I fix or re-structure these React components to avoid constant re-renders?

Tags: reactjs, performance, next.js

I have a Next.js page which displays a transcript's content and allows users to select bits of the transcript text and make notes on it.

**My problem is stated at the bottom**

Within `getServersideProps`, I fetch a link to the media file from S3 and the transcript from my DB:

```js
const mediaUrl = await getSignedUrl(file.uri);
const transcript = prisma.transcript.findUnique({ where: { fileId: fileId as string }}),
```

In the page, I extract the *words* from the transcript object and make a ref to the media HTML element:

```js
const mediaRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement | HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);
const { words } = transcript;
```

`transcript.words` looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "start": 3.9199998,
    "end": 4.12,
    "word": "this", 
    "speaker": 0,
    "speaker_confidence": 0.32493597
    "confidence": 0.5638778
    "punctuated_word": "This",
  },
...
]
```

I then render the HTML element to display the media file (vid/audio):

```js
{file.type === "VIDEO" ? (
    <video
        src={mediaUrl}
        controls
        ref={mediaRef as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLVideoElement>}
        className="lg:fixed lg:bottom-2 lg:left-2 lg:w-1/6 md:w-full z-50 w-full"
      />
    ) : (
      <audio
        src={mediaUrl}
        controls
        ref={mediaRef}
        className="sticky top-4 w-full z-50"
      />
)}
```

I then render the `Transcript` component:

```js
<Transcript
    transcript={words}
    audioRef={mediaRef}
    user={user}
    existingNotes={notes}
    fileId={fileId}
    projectId={projectId}
    summaryHasLoaded={summaryHasLoaded}
    tags={tags}
/>
```

The `Transcript` component has the following structure:

```js
interface ITranscriptProps {
  transcript: {
    start: number;
    end: number;
    speaker: number;
    speaker_confidence: number;
    punctuated_word: string;
    confidence: number;
    word: string;
  }[];
  audioRef: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLAudioElement | HTMLVideoElement | null>;
  user: User;
  existingNotes: NoteWithTagsAndCreator[];
  tags: TagWithNotes[];
  fileId: string;
  projectId: string;
  summaryHasLoaded: Boolean;
}
```

Within the `Transcript` component, I group the transcript words by their respective speakers, like so:

```js
const groupedTranscript = useMemo(() => {
    return new TranscriptGrouper(transcript).groupBySpeaker();
  }, [transcript]);
```

I have a state which keeps track of the current word, and a useEffect which checks the audio/video file and sets the currentWord based on the time:

```js
const [currentWord, setCurrentWord] = useState<number>(0);
useEffect(() => {
    const checkTime = () => {
      if (audioRef.current) {
        const currentTime = audioRef.current.currentTime;

        // loop through transcript to find the word that matches the current time
        for (let i = 0; i < transcript.length; i++) {
          if (
            currentTime >= transcript[i].start &&
            currentTime <= transcript[i].end
          ) {
            setCurrentWord(i);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // add timeupdate event listener to audioRef
    if (audioRef.current) {
      audioRef.current.addEventListener("timeupdate", checkTime);
    }

    return () => {
      // cleanup - remove the event listener
      if (audioRef.current) {
        audioRef.current.removeEventListener("timeupdate", checkTime);
      }
    };
  }, [audioRef, transcript]);
```

I have functions to handle selection of the transcript text as well as handle clicking on a word:

```js
const handleTextSelect = (start: number, end: number): void => {
    // Get the current selection from the window.
    const selection = window.getSelection();

    // Return early if no selection is made.
    if (!selection) return;

    // Extract the bounding rectangle of the selected text.
    const selectedTextRectangle = selection
      .getRangeAt(0)
      .getBoundingClientRect();

    // Update the 'selectedText' state with the details of the selection.
    setSelectedText({
      start,
      end,
      selectedTextRectangle,
    });
  };
```

```js
  const handleWordClick = useCallback(
    (start: number) => {
      if (audioRef.current) {
        audioRef.current.currentTime = start;
        audioRef.current.play();
      }
    },
    [audioRef]
  );
```

Within `<Transcript />`, I render `SpeakerName` `TranscriptText` components:

```js
return (
    <>
      <Box
        className="transcript-content-container"
        ref={transcriptContainerDivRef}
      >
        {groupedTranscript.map((group, groupIndex) => (
          <Box className="grouped-transcript" key={groupIndex}>
            <SpeakerName
              speaker={group.speaker}
              speakerNames={speakerNames}
              newSpeakerName={newSpeakerName}
              setNewSpeakerName={setNewSpeakerName}
              setSpeakerNames={setSpeakerNames}
              startingTimestamp={group.words[0].start}
              audioRef={audioRef}
            />
            <TranscriptText
              group={group}
              notes={notes}
              currentWord={currentWord}
              onTextSelect={handleTextSelect}
              onWordClick={handleWordClick}
            />
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Box>
```

This is what the  component looks like:

```js
interface IGroup {
  speaker: number;
  words: {
    start: number;
    end: number;
    speaker: number;
    punctuated_word: string;
    index: number;
  }[];
}

interface ITranscriptTextProps {
  group: IGroup;
  notes: NoteWithTagsAndCreator[];
  currentWord: number;
  onTextSelect: (_start: number, _end: number) => void;
  onWordClick: (_start: number) => void;
}

const DEFAULT_STYLE = {...};

const TranscriptText: React.FC<ITranscriptTextProps> = ({
  group,
  notes,
  currentWord,
  onTextSelect,
  onWordClick,
}) => {
  const getSelectedTextDetails = useSelectedTextDetails();
  const theme = useMantineTheme();

  const styles = useMemo(() => {...}, [theme]);

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    const selectedText = getSelectedTextDetails();
    selectedText && onTextSelect(selectedText.start, selectedText.end);
  };

  return (
    <Text onMouseUp={handleMouseUp} lh={1.7}>
      {group.words.map((word) => {
        const isNote = notes.some(
          (note) => word.start >= note.start && word.end <= note.end
        );

        const isCurrentWord = word.index === currentWord;

        const currentWordStyle = isCurrentWord ? {...} : {};

        const combinedStyle = {...};

        return (
          <span
            key={word.index}
            data-start={word.start}
            data-end={word.end}
            style={combinedStyle}
            onClick={() => onWordClick(word.start)}
          >
            {word.punctuated_word + " "}
          </span>
        );
      })}
    </Text>
  );
};

export default React.memo(TranscriptText);
```

**My problem**: there are a lot of re-renders, which is causing performance issues. As you've seen above, the components sync a video/audio file with it's transcript, and highlights the current word that is being spoken in the video. Every time the current word changes, almost everything re-renders. For example, if `groupedTranscript` returns 100 different groups (i.e., speaker 1 speaks for a minute, then speaker 2 speaks for 3 minutes, etc., and each of those will be groups), then upon word change, all 100 are being re-rendered. This is causing significant performance issues.

I am wondering how I can fix this problem, or maybe if I should restructure the components a different way?

I've tried optimizing using `useMemo` and `useCallback` hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memoize the `TranscriptText` component, remove the `currentWord` from it's props, and remove the style handling of words.

Create a context for handling selections of words.

Create a `Word` component that would handle it's own selected state, and would register to the context.

**Example** - you can see that the `TranscriptText` component is only rendered once, although the words are selected one by one.

```js
const { useState, memo, createContext, useRef, useEffect, useCallback, useContext } = React

const SelectWordContext = createContext(() => {})

const SelectWord = ({ currentWordIdx, children }) => {
  const wordsSelect = useRef([])
  const prevWordIdx = useRef(currentWordIdx)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(currentWordIdx < 0 || currentWordIdx === prevWordIdx.current) return
    
    wordsSelect.current[prevWordIdx.current] && wordsSelect.current[prevWordIdx.current](false) // optional chanining wordsSelect.current[prevWordIdx.current]?.(false)
    
    wordsSelect.current[currentWordIdx] && wordsSelect.current[currentWordIdx](true) // optional chanining wordsSelect.current[currentWordIdx]?.(true)
    
    prevWordIdx.current = currentWordIdx
  }, [currentWordIdx]);
  
  const registerWord = useCallback((selectWord, idx) => {
    wordsSelect.current[idx] = selectWord
  }, [])

  return (
    <SelectWordContext.Provider value={registerWord}>
    {children}
    </SelectWordContext.Provider>
  )
}

const Word = ({ word, idx }) => {
  const register = useContext(SelectWordContext)
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    register(setSelected, idx)
  }, [idx])
  
  return <span style={{ 
    color: selected ? 'red' : 'inherit',
  }}>{word} </span>
}

const TranscriptText = memo(({ words }) => {
  console.log('render TranscriptText')
  
  return (
    <div>
    {words.map((word, idx) => ( // idx is used as the key just for the demo, avoid in real apps
      <Word word={word} idx={idx} key={idx} />
    ))}
    </div>
  )
})

const Demo = ({ words }) => {
  const [currentWordIdx, setCurrentWordIdx] = useState(-1);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => 
      setCurrentWordIdx(i => i + 1)
    , 1000)
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <SelectWord currentWordIdx={currentWordIdx}>
      <div>
        <TranscriptText words={words} />
      </div>
    </SelectWord>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo words={getWords()} />)
  
function getWords() {
  return ["Lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet","consectetur","adipiscing","elit","Pellentesque","lectus","lorem","semper","sit","amet","elementum","at","ullamcorper","porttitor","ipsum","Donec","blandit","lectus","mattis","dui","rutrum","eu","consequat","nisl","sodales","Aenean","ac","blandit","ligula","Donec","scelerisque","dictum","elit","at","porta","justo","suscipit","ut","Quisque","pharetra","ligula","ornare","tincidunt","ligula","sit","amet","volutpat","ipsum","Nullam","cursus","ligula","et","massa","imperdiet","convallis","Aliquam","enim","sapien","facilisis","ut","venenatis","quis","accumsan","et","neque","Sed","vel","odio","eu","neque","vulputate","hendrerit","ut","vitae","tortor","Aliquam","et","vulputate","orci","Suspendisse","vitae","orci","diam","Quisque","vitae","maximus","augue","Cras","sagittis","nibh","sagittis","turpis","hendrerit","elementum","Morbi","eleifend","fringilla","ipsum","ultrices","efficitur","Quisque","est","nisl","finibus","quis","suscipit","non","interdum","quis","neque","Pellentesque","habitant","morbi","tristique","senectus","et","netus","et","malesuada","fames","ac","turpis","egestas","Sed","tempor","ac","ligula","vel","egestas","Sed","in","volutpat","justo","et","sagittis","magna","Quisque","rutrum","arcu","eu","odio","tincidunt","a","condimentum","sem","dictum","Etiam","quis","efficitur","massa","tincidunt","viverra","quam","Nulla","in","tincidunt","felis","et","imperdiet","mi","Morbi","eleifend","non","felis","id","efficitur","Integer","et","pulvinar","nibh","in","blandit","neque","Maecenas","vitae","venenatis","sapien","at","gravida","ligula","Etiam","volutpat","at","orci","eu","luctus","Lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet","consectetur","adipiscing","elit","Morbi","commodo","sollicitudin","sem","quis","volutpat","Phasellus","finibus","libero","vel","commodo","accumsan","Vivamus","sed","elit","purus","Ut","egestas","dui","nisi","sed","imperdiet","risus","consequat","commodo","Cras","convallis","pretium","massa","id","elementum","nulla","convallis","id","Mauris","et","gravida","velit","Etiam","egestas","metus","sagittis","elit","luctus","quis","laoreet","quam","sollicitudin","Praesent","posuere","pulvinar","velit","quis","hendrerit","Nulla","condimentum","quis","orci","non","vulputate","Donec","quis","nisl","nibh","Nulla","tincidunt","sapien","nec","dui","tincidunt","accumsan","Phasellus","tempus","ipsum","at","ipsum","vulputate","quis","posuere","nisi","bibendum","Integer","dolor","lorem","egestas","eu","erat","vel","ultrices","placerat","nibh","Morbi","bibendum","lacus","id","ex","hendrerit","ornare","Etiam","nec","massa","magna","Pellentesque","id","pulvinar","odio","rhoncus","scelerisque","ex","Ut","suscipit","eu","ligula","eget","fringilla","Pellentesque","sed","tempor","ante","Sed","ultricies","sit","amet","dolor","et","mattis","Nam","sodales","risus","ut","nisl","dictum","sit","amet","consequat","odio","accumsan","Curabitur","bibendum","hendrerit","enim","ac","suscipit","Maecenas","id","orci","quam","Nullam","sed","ante","urna","Curabitur","varius","sem","sit","amet","pretium","mattis","Vivamus","nec","risus","quam","Vestibulum","commodo","ligula","eu","dui","volutpat","feugiat","Donec","nec","aliquam","nunc","a","lobortis","justo","Etiam","vulputate","magna","mauris","vel","sodales","mauris","sollicitudin","eget","Curabitur","pellentesque","rhoncus","metus","quis","luctus","magna","tincidunt","id","Aenean","porttitor","hendrerit","tortor","facilisis","egestas"]
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```